# Deploying CLR UDFs to SQL Server 2008 in a replicated environment?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am running SQL Server 2008 with replication enabled.  I have a .NET CLR database project with UDFs that I would like to deploy to SQL Server, however the objects are marked for replication.  What's the preferred way to deploy in this scenario?  Do I need to run a script before deployment that unmarks these for replication and then remarks them after deployment?  Does that force me to recreate a new snapshot?  Can I run these scripts automatically in Visual Studio as part of the deployment process?

Comment: I think it's not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to deploy these only to your main server or are you trying to ensure the updates are replicated? The way you have written the question is a bit confusing.

Comment: The server I'm deploying the CLR procs/UDFs to is the publisher, not any of the subscribers.  The procs/UDFs should be pushed then as part of the replication to any subscribers.  Trouble is, you cannot drop items marked for replication, hence it's a pain to deploy your CLR objects.  Just wondering if there's a best practice for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to mark them as not replicated, deploy and then remark them as replicated.

Your current snapshot won't be valid so you'll have to generate a new one, but you can wait the 
That's what we do and I don't see how you can do otherwise.